# Elasticsearch - Grouping aggregation - 2 fields

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

My mapping is

```
{
"myapp": {
    "mappings": {
        "attempts": {
            "properties": {
                "answers": {
                    "properties": {
                        "question_id": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "status": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "exam_id": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and i want to group by question_id and status

I want to know for every question_id how many has status 1 or 2

P.S. 2 attempts can have the same questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All, you need to update your mapping and make `answers` a [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html) field. Not making it `nested` will make the answers to lose the correlation between `question_id` field and `status` field.

```
{
"myapp": {
    "mappings": {
        "attempts": {
            "properties": {
                "answers": {
                    "type":"nested", <-- Update here
                    "properties": {
                        "question_id": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "status": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "exam_id": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

You can use status in a sub-aggregation as shown below

```
"aggs": {
    "nested_qid_agg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "answers"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "qid": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "answers.question_id",
            "size": 0
          },
          "aggs": {
            "status": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "answers.status",
                "size": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```